# Understanding yum error

Tags: yum, dependencies

Here is the error message I get when I try to do a yum update.

```
Error: Package: 389-ds-base-snmp-1.3.10.2-9.el7_9.x86_64 (@rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional)
       Requires: 389-ds-base = 1.3.10.2-9.el7_9
       Removing: 389-ds-base-1.3.10.2-9.el7_9.x86_64 (@rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.10.2-9.el7_9
       Updated By: 389-ds-base-1.3.11.1-4.el7_9.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.11.1-4.el7_9
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.1.6-25.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.1.6-25.el7
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.1.6-26.el7_0.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.1.6-26.el7_0
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.3.1-13.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.3.1-13.el7
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.3.1-15.el7_1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.3.1-15.el7_1
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.3.1-16.el7_1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.3.1-16.el7_1
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.3.1-20.el7_1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.3.1-20.el7_1
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.3.1-23.el7_1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.3.1-23.el7_1
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.4.0-19.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.4.0-19.el7
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.4.0-21.el7_2.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.4.0-21.el7_2
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.4.0-26.el7_2.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.4.0-26.el7_2
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.4.0-29.el7_2.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.4.0-29.el7_2
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.4.0-30.el7_2.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.4.0-30.el7_2
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.4.0-32.el7_2.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.4.0-32.el7_2
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.4.0-33.el7_2.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.4.0-33.el7_2
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.5.10-11.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.5.10-11.el7
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.5.10-12.el7_3.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.5.10-12.el7_3
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.5.10-15.el7_3.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.5.10-15.el7_3
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.5.10-18.el7_3.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.5.10-18.el7_3
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.5.10-20.el7_3.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.5.10-20.el7_3
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.5.10-21.el7_3.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.5.10-21.el7_3
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.6.1-16.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.6.1-16.el7
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.6.1-19.el7_4.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.6.1-19.el7_4
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.6.1-21.el7_4.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.6.1-21.el7_4
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.6.1-24.el7_4.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.6.1-24.el7_4
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.6.1-26.el7_4.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.6.1-26.el7_4
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.6.1-28.el7_4.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.6.1-28.el7_4
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.6.1-29.el7_4.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.6.1-29.el7_4
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.7.5-18.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.7.5-18.el7
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.7.5-19.el7_5.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.7.5-19.el7_5
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.7.5-21.el7_5.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.7.5-21.el7_5
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.7.5-24.el7_5.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.7.5-24.el7_5
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.7.5-25.el7_5.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.7.5-25.el7_5
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.7.5-28.el7_5.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.7.5-28.el7_5
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.8.4-15.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.8.4-15.el7
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.8.4-18.el7_6.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.8.4-18.el7_6
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.8.4-22.el7_6.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.8.4-22.el7_6
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.8.4-23.el7_6.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.8.4-23.el7_6
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.8.4-25.1.el7_6.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.8.4-25.1.el7_6
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.9.1-10.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.9.1-10.el7
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.9.1-12.el7_7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.9.1-12.el7_7
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.9.1-13.el7_7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.9.1-13.el7_7
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.10.1-5.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.10.1-5.el7
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.10.1-9.el7_8.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.10.1-9.el7_8
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.10.1-14.el7_8.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.10.1-14.el7_8
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.10.2-6.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.10.2-6.el7
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.10.2-7.1.el7_9.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.10.2-7.1.el7_9
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.10.2-8.el7_9.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.10.2-8.el7_9
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.10.2-10.el7_9.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.10.2-10.el7_9
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.10.2-12.el7_9.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.10.2-12.el7_9
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.10.2-13.el7_9.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.10.2-13.el7_9
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.10.2-14.el7_9.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.10.2-14.el7_9
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.10.2-15.el7_9.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.10.2-15.el7_9
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.10.2-16.el7_9.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.10.2-16.el7_9
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.10.2-17.el7_9.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.10.2-17.el7_9
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.11.1-1.el7_9.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.11.1-1.el7_9
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.11.1-2.el7_9.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.11.1-2.el7_9
       Available: 389-ds-base-1.3.11.1-3.el7_9.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms)
           389-ds-base = 1.3.11.1-3.el7_9
```

I see that it shows 389-ds-base-1.3.10.2-9.el7_9.x86_64 is missing but when I do this:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep 389-ds-base
389-ds-base-1.3.10.2-9.el7_9.x86_64
389-ds-base-snmp-1.3.10.2-9.el7_9.x86_64
389-ds-base-libs-1.3.10.2-9.el7_9.x86_64
```

it shows that it is installed. I have no idea what to do and I've been trying to find out via logs or other posts but am having no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [Resolving Dependency Errors](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/resolving-dependency-errors-in-rhel-yum-with-python%2A-packages-4175634150/) and ended up just deleting the package that was holding it up (389-ds-base-snmp-1.3.10.2-9.el7_9.x86_64). after deleting it I was able to run yum update successfully.

I noticed the snmp package was not there anymore and saw the optional-rpm repo was not enabled, so after enabling that I was able to update to the latest package.